# University preventing staff from taking trips with students?

Tags: united-states, privacy, students

My university recently put a staff member on leave of absence after the staffer took a weekend kayaking trip with several students, citing "unprofessional conduct".  The staffer is a kayaking instructor for the university, and the students were all experienced kayakers and not (to my knowledge) his students.

This seems to me to be effectively a prohibition on staffers being friends with students.  Is there a precedent for this?  What business is it of the university to police what staff and students do in their own free time?

Comment: Public or private university?

Comment: It literally is their business, managing the relationships between staff and students to achieve a variety of outcomes (the main one being education and the award of qualifications, but far from the only thing).

Comment: State jurisdiction?  Also the source from which you heard about the situation (friend of the kayakers?  Of the staffer?  Uni announcement of the situation? Rumor Mill?  News Paper (school publication or professional journalist source?)